# Unable to extract value for Z3 EnumSort in z3py

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I am currently trying to encode a problem into Z3, and I wish to model a "tristate" Boolean (i.e., a Boolean with `true`, `false` and `unknown`).

Here is how I have modelled it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import z3
from collections import OrderedDict

TristateValues = ["True", "False", "Unknown"]
Tristate, consts = z3.EnumSort("Tristate", TristateValues)
TristateValues = OrderedDict(zip(TristateValues, consts))

s = z3.Solver()
x = z3.Const("x", Tristate)
s.add(x != TristateValues["Unknown"])
value = s.check()
if value == z3.sat:
    m = s.model()
    print str(m.eval(x))
else:
    print str(value)

# EOF
```

And on this small example, things work well, and I get values such as `True` or `False`.

However, on larger examples, I get results such as:

- `Tristate!val!0`
- `Tristate!val!1`
- `Tristate!val!2`

Clearly, it seems that there would be a mapping between these "Tristate" strings and the real values, so I wrote something like this:

```
ModelToTristate = {}

as_list = list(TristateValues.keys())
for idx in range(0, len(as_list)):
    ModelToTristate["Tristate!val!{:d}".format(idx)] = as_list[idx]
```

to try and map back between the values (this is why the use of `OrderedDict` is important to preserve the ordering).

And, initially, it seemed that this worked. However, I then hit some more, stranger errors:

- I'd eventually get lookup errors into `ModelToTristate` where it seems I was indeed getting the correct value for calling `str` on the result of `model.eval()` (i.e., Z3 would give `True`, `False`, etc. rather than than `Tristate!val!*`)
- I'd get inconsistencies in the model (e.g., even when asserting `x == Tristate["False"]`, checking the look-up would result in `model.eval(x) == Tristate!val!1`, where `Tristate!val!1` maps to `True`)

For this last issue, I think there is a lookup problem, rather than Z3 giving incorrect values.

So, my question is: what is causing Z3 to use these `Tristate!val!*` strings, and can I "force" Z3 to use the correct values (i.e., `True`, `False`, `Unknown`)?

I am using Z3 4.5.0.

**Update** after checking it, it seems that this problem appears when I use `SolverFor("QF_ABV")`.

Answer (score 1):

The QF_ABV logic does not know about algebraic datatypes. It will treat them as uninterpreted. The model you get back then is as if the enumeration sort is free.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolaj! That makes sense, glad I realised I was using ABV in my other code.